# TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '_Fire2.default.auth.onAuthStateChanged') React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I a trying to authenticate my react native expo app with firebase login signup, I don't know why my app I giving this issue but if someone knows ill be thankful.
[Here I have also attached screenshot of my error on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUnfM.png)

Error is in `App.js` file where I have mentioned that in which line the error is happening.
My source code is here below,

In `fire.js` I have just put my firebase authentication details.
fire.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAQmlKQO5H0bTnjOgKZn50_FWmgMccmQLw",
    authDomain: "savapp-3dd0f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://savapp-3dd0f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "savapp-3dd0f",
    storageBucket: "savapp-3dd0f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "456931428577"
};
const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);
export default fire;
```

Here in login.js I have made an interface where all the login process is happening and then I have imported it in App.js  file.
Login.js

```
import fire from './Fire';
constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state=
    {
      email:'',
      password:''
    }
  }

  login()
  {
    fire.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email , this.state.password).then((u)=>{
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

And finally it's `App.js` where the error is happening and I have also mentioned in comment form where error is happening.
App.js

import fire from './app/components/Fire'

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
      super(props);
      this.authListener = this.authListener.bind(this);
      this.state={
        user:{},
      }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
      this.authListener();
    }

    authListener()
    { 
      fire.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => { //Here error is happening
        if(user)
        {
          this.setState({user});
        }
        else
        {
          this.setState({user:null});
        }
      })
    }
```

Comment: May be you have some typo mistake, `fire.auth().onAuthStateChange(...)`

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy I don't think so. I have mentioned code also if you can see any mistake than please tell

Comment: Sounds like an import statement was off. Check if the path of the import statement is correct.  `import fire from './app/components/Fire'`